# Are there any free HTML content displayer in Silverlight?

Tags: html, silverlight, editor, controls

hi i am looking for an HTML control for **Silverlight** which is free where it is capable of **editing HTML** and **displaying read-only HTML** content

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To edit the HTML. I see no reason why you could not just use an ordinary textbox. As far as displaying HTML, have you considered trying to hijack the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control? Just beware that it will only work outside the browser. That will certainly show you HTML.

If you're looking for a full blown HTML editor, I'm not sure if such a thing exists.

Comment: thanks but im looking for "in browser" not "out of browser" true TextBox for html editing is fine but it needs to be like RichTextBox where we could edit add hyperlinks insert images etc and once save it it saves in the DB the problem is i am looking for something like RichText that can even contain images in it and then save it to the DB as rtf instead of xaml but instead of all this headache if there is any html full functioning control i would be very glad to use it